# Is it a risk to highlight text while reading a webpage?

Tags: web-browser, javascript

Whenever a user selects or highlights text on a webpage, an `OnClick()` event is generated.  Some of the web browser security models depends on explicit end user interaction, such as `OnClick()`, before a new tab is opened, or software is downloaded.

- That being said, is it a risk to highlight text while reading a webpage?
- What can be done to mitigate this risk?

Comment: Excellent question.  As an inveterate highlighter, I'm often slammed when I hit a web site that pops up ads in response to OnClick() events.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds related to what NoScript's [ClearClick](http://hackademix.net/2008/10/08/hello-clearclick-goodbye-clickjacking/) is designed to prevent.  (The protection applies even if you have NoScript set to "Allow Scripts Globally").

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say just about anything isn't a risk if javascript is on.  As far as I know, there is no good way to tell where an exploit might exist.  That said, if you are really concerned about highlighting text on a page without risk, my recommendations would be to either a) turn off scripts such that onclick events don't occur, b) view source and copy the text directly out of the source or c) if the text is not available in the source, use a tool like firebug which can inspect the DOM and pull the text directly out of the DOM.

In general no-script on a site you don't trust is just good security to begin with though as there have been exploits that don't even require direct interaction with the page beyond simply loading it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the only risk could be your privacy since there are some widgets that sends back to the server what text you have selected.
Browser add-ons such as [Ghostery](http://www.ghostery.com/) blocks these intrusive scripts.

Comment: -1 Ghostery does its own nasty tracking and profiling. It is a cure worse than the disease.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't any user triggered event be a problem and not just OnClick?

But directly relevant to your question is clickjacking: https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=clickjacking

Answer (score 0):

> That being said, is it a risk to highlight text while reading a
>   webpage?

There isn't a risk unless the browser has an exploit dealing when text is highlighted.

> What can be done to mitigate this risk?

Any browser worth using wouldn't have an exploit.

I won't even address the concerns raised by AJ dealing with JavaScript mainly because that risk is unique to a given browser's engine.

Comment: "Any browser worth using wouldn't have an exploit." That's bold. They all seem to have various flaws at different times.